# Wordpress get posts that are in multiple categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm tring to use 'category__and' filter in WP_Query function to get some posts out and I get nothing!

here's my code:

```
$query_args = array( 'category__and' => array(44,43), 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'no_found_rows' => 1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'product');
$r = new WP_Query($query_args);
if ($r->have_posts()) { ............
```

Important note:
I have posts in both categories 44&43.
When I remove the 'category__and' I get all posts.

Comment: `category__and` sounds like something that requires posts to be in *both* categories. Isn't there a `category__or`?

Comment: Hey, yes there is category__in, but I want it that way (I require post to be in both categories).

Comment: You are 100% sure that you have at least one post of the right type that is in *both* category 43 and 44 at the same time?

Comment: Yes I already check it like 100 times... But even when I change the category__and to category_in I get **nothing**!

Comment: Very strange. I have no other explanation except that something's wrong with the post's categories.

Comment: Continuing from @Pekka's statement... or with the `post_status` or `post_type`. Remove everything but `'category__and' => array(44,43), 'posts_per_page' => 9` and see what happens.